# $L(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h}(t),\mathbf{\dot{x}}+\mathbf{\dot{h}}(t))$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth map and use coordinates $\mathbf{q}=(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ on the first factor and $\mathbf{\dot{q}}=(\dot{q_1},\ldots,\dot{q_n})$ on the second factor. Dots do not indicate derivatives.

I am trying to understand why
$$L(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h}(t),\mathbf{\dot{x}}+\mathbf{\dot{h}}(t))=L(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\dot{x}})+\sum_i\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\dot{x}})h_i(t)+\sum_i\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_i}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\dot{x}})\dot{h}_i(t)+o(||\mathbf{h}||).$$

Does the smoothness of $L$ imply that it is bilinear?

If it is bilinear, it is clear to me where the first and the last term come from, but I cannot see how to get the middle two terms. Where do the partial derivatives come from? If it is not bilinear, I do understand why it can be split up in this way.

Comment: This is the Taylor expansion to first order of a function $L:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{R}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables for more details

Comment: @Joshhh That makes sense. Thank you!